# AVFoundation how to add subtitles track to AVComposition

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation, subtitle, avcomposition

I want to add a track of type AVMediaTypeSubtitle to AVMutableComposition
the adding itself is easy, but how to populate this Track? and how to read it later?!!

I can't find any thing related to how to read/write a track of type AVMediaTypeSubtitle !!

Comment: did you try to load your AVAssetTrack with an .srt file to see how it works?

Comment: you can't load AVAssetTrack, but you can load AVAsset, and yes I tried
and it didn't recognize any thing

Comment: did you try to load (IDX/SUB) format?

Comment: no, but I tried .scc and nothing
you know that it works somehow or you are guessing?
and what about reading, let's say I've mp4 file that has on it a subtitle track, how to play it???

Comment: no no, i have no idea but i would be interested in knowing because indeed i cant find info about this trackType either.

Comment: then I think voting up the question may be a good idea

Comment: I did upvote your question.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice

Comment: Did you try https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/ ?